# Jsp:forward redirection

Tags: jsp, forward

I have a page called `story.jsp` (this is the parent page) & in `story.jsp`, based on certain condition I am forwarding (using `jsp:forward`) the page to some other story page path like `../business/story.jsp`.

So in this scenario please let me know, whether the response again comes to the parent page or it will execute the `../business/story.jsp` & serve to the browser 
or 
it will come to the parent `story.jsp` & execute its contents as well.

I am totally confused please help me.

Please let me know the details.

Comment: I put the logger in both jsp in parent as well as child also but sometime it will print the log from both JSP thats why I am confuse really what its doing I just want to know how the JSP:forward will work therotically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a `forward` (`jsp:forward`) as the name suggests, it will forward the request i.e. terminate execution of the current page `story.jsp` and transfer all the control to the next jsp to which it has forwarded. So the browser will serve only the content of your `../business/story.jsp`.

Where as, if you do a `include` (`jsp:include`), then as the name suggests the control is transferred back to your parent page after executing that included page i.e. the browser will serve contents of both the JSPs.